# ping на другой компьютер

Tags: windows, сеть, ping

Хай! Есть 2 компьютера. 1 подключен к интернету через wifi роутер, 2ой, через прямой кабель (PPP адаптер). Почему 2 эти компьютера не пингуются между собой (timeout)?
И почему если кабель подключен напрямую, без роутера, то в ipconfig'e и на сайте cmyip показываются разные IP? Какой вводить для команды ping на другом компьютере? (пробовал оба, пакеты не передаются, timeout). Спасибо!

Comment: Причин может быть просто туча. Разные подсети, блокировка антивируса/firewall, запрет на ping и т.д.

Comment: @LEQADA фаерволы\брандмауэры отключены на обоих девайсах.

Comment: @LEQADA а антивирус может блокировать отправку запроса? Т.е. компьютер с антивирусом не может пинговать другие компьютеры.

Comment: Антивирус скорее заблокирует входящий запрос.

Comment: @LEQADA, не, мы друг друга не видим. Но пинговать тот же google.com можем. Он не пингует меня, а я его...